# Putting dynamically created ID into javascript

Tags: php, javascript

So I have a script that auto-generates ID's based on a column in a database. like such:

```
echo "<tr class='task' id='task-" . $row['task_id'] . "'>";
```

And then I have a script that is below that I am wanting it to change each tr class name based on some information from another column. I tried placing the same code `'task-". $row[task_id] ."'` into the `document.getElementById` field but it didn't resolve in the browser. resolve meaning it stayed as `'task-" . $row[task_id] . "'` instead of changing $row[task_id] into a number. I need to make that change to a number so it matches the id's of the `tr`.

```
var resolved = <?php echo $_SESSION['resolved']; ?>;
    if (resolved == 1) 
    {
        document.getElementById('task-" . $row[task_id] . "').className ="task resolved";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('task-" . $row[task_id] . "').className =" task";
    }
```

Comment: Why are you generating JavaScript with PHP? I'm pretty sure you can do this without mixing the two together.

Comment: Then how do you do this? That is my question.

Comment: Do you have the resolved status in the database table? per ID line?

Comment: Like are you just trying to apply classes, wheteher a line item is resolved or not?

Comment: if you mean if i have a task_id for each row, then yes.

Comment: But where are you getting the 'resolved' information from

Comment: kyleK.... I am wanting to make the class name `task resolved` if `resolved == 1` `if resolved == 0` then I want the task class name to be `task`

Comment: I get that....but where is resolved coming from, how do you know if a row is resolved or not....the data has to come from somewhere

Comment: I have a row in my databased called resolved and it is either 1 or 0 for each entry

Comment: Ok, so why are you using javascript at all then?  Just do it with php

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm just not extremely trained in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to echo out the variables like so:

```
var resolved = <?php echo $_SESSION['resolved']; ?>;

if (resolved == 1) 
{
    document.getElementById('task-<?php echo $row['task_id'] ?>').className ="task resolved";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('task-<?php echo $row['task_id'] ?>').className =" task";
}
```

But it's better to not do it in javascript but to just do it in your PHP like so:

```
echo "<tr class='task " . ($_SESSION['resolved'] == 1 ? 'resolved' : '') ."' id='task-" . $row['task_id'] . "'>";
```

that adds the `resolved` class to as you are generating your HTML.  However you will probably need a better way to test if a task is resolved because with the `$_SESSION['resolved'] == 1` it's going to mark ALL tasks as resolved. So assuming your row has a column like `$row['resolved'] you could do:

```
echo "<tr class='task " . ($row['resolved'] == 1 ? 'resolved' : '') . "' id='task-$row[task_id]'>";
```

Comment: Your two new lines have errors...you're echoing and then opening php tags, but they would already be open, cause you're echoing.

Comment: @KyleK Thanks Kyle I got copy/paste happy haha. should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

No need for javascript, if your status is in a column of that table....

```
if($row['resolved']=="1){
    $class="task resolved";
} else {$class = "task";}

echo "<tr class='".$class."' id='task-" . $row['task_id'] . "'>";
```

Or a much simpler version...

```
echo "<tr class='task ".($row['resolved'] == 1 ? 'resolved' : '')."' id='task-".$row['task_id']."'>";
```